# Superluminal group velocity in Lossy waveguides

Tags: electromagnetism, speed-of-light, waveguide

Let's consider a waveguide with $2$ perfect electric boundary conditions filled with a lossy medium modelled with conductivity $\sigma$ and permittivity $\epsilon$ and permeability $\mu$.

It is possible to show that the solutions are the same as for non lossy waveguide but with the following dispersion relation : 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:PECdispersion}
 k_0^2n^2 = k_x^2 + k_y^2
  ~~\mbox{with}~~ 
 k_y =\frac{m\pi}{a} 
 ~~\mbox{and}~~ 
 n^2 = \mu\epsilon(1 - j\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon})
 ~~\mbox{and}~~ 
\end{equation}

The real part $\beta$ of the complex wave vector component $k_x=\beta-j\alpha$ is known as the propagation constant and depends on $\omega$. 
The group velocity of the wave of frequency $\omega_0$ is $v_g(\omega_0)=\frac{d\beta(\omega)}{d\omega}_{|\omega_0}$.

Using the above expression of the dispersion relation, one can show that for sufficiently small values of $\omega$, the group velocity exceeds the speed of light in the medium.

**I have encountered situations with superluminal group velocity and been told that the only physical velocity is the velocity of the wavefront of the wave which will necessarily be below c. But what happens if I excite the waveguide at only one of these waves whose frequency is sufficiently small ? Should not I see the wave going faster than the speed of light?**